# Content Security Setting for manifest file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, content-security-policy, nwebsec

We've been implementing Content Security Policy using NWebsec & Asp.Net MVC5 and have it mostly working .

However, we haven't been able to configure to allow access to "manifest.json" file.  There doesn't appear to be a way to set the "manifest-src" setting.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `manifest-src` directive is currently not supported in NWebsec, but it's scheduled for the next version: https://github.com/NWebsec/NWebsec/issues/91

In lack of the `manifest-src` directive , the `default-src` directive will limit where manifests can be loaded from. See https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#directive-default-src